# linking error compiling with Qt 4

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have a project which i started building with QT5 but since other people in the company use QT4, I tried making it back compatible. I was able to get all the includes etc work right but there is a linking error I can't figure out.

## The error is :

```
compiling gen/Release/obj/qrc_map_markup_gui.cpp
linking bin/visual_route_generationmap_markup_gui
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.49, needed by /other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicuuc.so.49, needed by /other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_compareNames_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucol_close_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucol_setAttribute_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_toUnicode_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ures_getStringByKey_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `u_strToUpper_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_countAvailable_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucol_open_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `u_strToLower_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_getDefaultName_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_getStandardName_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucol_getAttribute_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_countAliases_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ures_open_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ures_close_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_close_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucol_strcoll_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_setSubstChars_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_fromUnicode_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_getAvailableName_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_getAlias_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucol_getSortKey_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_getMaxCharSize_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `ucnv_open_49'
/other/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5: undefined reference to `u_errorName_49'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [bin/visual_route_generationmap_markup_gui] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lucid/other/workspace/perception/visual_route_generation/map_markup_gui'
make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

==================================================================================

Its still trying to use QT5 libraries. I have removed all the set variables from .bashrc.
How do I make the pro files look only for qt4 libs ?

Comment: Did you try to delete all generated Makefiles and run qmake again (but use Qt4 qmake)?

Comment: How have you installed your libraries?

Comment: Hey Yeh I run qmake-qt4 . And I have all the libs installed

Comment: I think the problem is that I need to specify exactly where the libs are

Comment: which operating system is this? You will need to have icu installed yourself.... Is it windows? Also, please quote others with @Name because they will not get a notification otherwise...

Comment: Has the issue been resolved?

Comment: Yeah it has. It was just about adding libs which I didn't know how to at at point. and also installing correct (older) libs.